# How to change wordpress pages permalink to RTL?

Tags: php, wordpress

**How Can I Change Place of page and child page in RTL language in Wordpress?**

I Installed RTL Wordpress with `x theme` And I have 2 pages:
`RTL Parent Page` as Parent and `RTL Child Page` as Child.

**Example in English:**
http://example.com/`Parent Page`/`Child Page`  //correct

**But in My Site in address bar I have:**
http://example.com/`RTL Child Page`/`RTL Parent Page`  // Not Correct

Comment: Hi would you mind to share your site url and  RTL plugin url plz (if any)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Temporary Fix**

Add an English letter or word at the begin of `RTL Child Page` link.